# Jmeter- is it possible to assign a unique thread number for each thread created in distributed testing

Tags: jmeter

Test plan has 2 thread groups. I am executing test plan in distributed testing mode from command line on 2 slave systems with 1 user load. So totally 4 users load.

Expected: In the CSV export, I need a counter to know unique threads initiated.. So i expect Thread-1 for first thread initiation, Thread-2 for second thread initiation, Thread-3 for third and Thread-4 for fourth irrespective of on which slave the thread was initiated.
If it is possible to assign a number to reach initiated thread irrespective of the slave, it should resolve.
This will help me to know the total unique threads initiated.

At present, CSV export has Thread-1, Thread-2 repeated in both the Slaves and I will not know how many unique threads were initiated upon execution unless I manually sun it up. This problem magnifies for me as the number of thread group and users increase.

Please let me know if there is a way that achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for the moment as "slave" machines are more or less independent, the only receive test plan (and properties) from master and report back results.

If you need to distinguish results coming from this or that remote slave a good practice is using [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function as a prefix or postfix to your Thread Groups or even individual samplers.

[image: JMeter MachineIP function Demo]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept and learn some more use cases.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the confirmation.